# Diferencias entre clases nombradas y clases anónimas en PHP 7

Tags: php, poo

Dentro del paradigma de la POO en la mayoría de los lenguajes tenemos a las clases como aquel elemento que encierra atributos y métodos afines; de este modo

**CLASES NOMBRADAS**

```
<?php

class humanBeign
{
    private $name;
    public function sayHi($name)
    {
        return "Hi: {$name}";
    }
}

$obj1 = new humanBeign();
echo $obj1->sayHi("Alfredo");
```

Ahora en PHP 7 tenemos las clases anónimas de este modo

**CLASES ANÓNIMAS**

```
<?php

$saludo = new Class("Hola comunidad de SO en español"){
    private $comunidad = "SO";

    public function __construct($comunidad)
    {
        $this->comunidad = $comunidad;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {   
        return $this->comunidad;
    }
};


echo $saludo->__toString();
```

**Preguntas**

1. ¿Cuáles son las diferencias entre una y otra?

> No pido opiniones sobre si una es mejor que otra o similar, pido
>   únicamente sus diferencias; **pues no me queda claro cuando usar una u
>   otra**

Comment: El Manual lo dice muy claro: *[`En PHP 7 se ha añadido soporte para clases anónimas. Las clases anónimas son útiles cuando es necesario crear objetos sencillos y únicos.`](http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.anonymous.php)*

Comment: Lo sé pero no me queda claro a mi por eso la pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta respuesta está basada en el [documento de presentación de las clases anónimas](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/anonymous_classes), introducidas en PHP 7.

Lo traduzco al castellano porque la explicación es completa y así contamos con ella para futuras referencias.

### Introducción

Durante algún tiempo, PHP ha ofrecido soporte de funciones anónimas en forma de Closures (cierres); este parche<sup>1</sup> introduce el mismo tipo de funcionalidad para los objetos de una clase anónima.

La capacidad de crear objetos de una clase anónima es una parte establecida y bien utilizada de la programación orientada a objetos en otros lenguajes (es decir, C # y Java).

Una clase anónima podría usarse sobre una clase nombrada <sup>2</sup>:

- cuando la clase no necesita ser documentada
- cuando la clase se usa solo una vez durante la ejecución

Una clase anónima es una clase sin un nombre (programado declarado). La funcionalidad del objeto no es diferente de la de un objeto de una clase nombrada. Usan la sintaxis existente para las clases, pero sin nombre [de clase]:

```
var_dump(new class($i) {
    public function __construct($i) {
        $this->i = $i;
    }
});
```

---

### Sintaxis y ejemplos

```
new class (argumentos) {definición}
```

Nota: en una versión anterior de este RFC, los argumentos estaban después de la definición, esto se ha cambiado para reflejar la retroalimentación durante la última discusión.

```
$util->setLogger(new class {
    public function log($msg)
    {
        echo $msg;
    }
});
```

Nota: la capacidad de declarar y usar un constructor en una clase anónima es necesaria cuando se debe ejercer control sobre la construcción.

---

### Herencia / Rasgos

Extender las clases funciona tal como lo esperas.

Cabe destacar que una clase anónima ofrece las mismas posibilidades que una clase normal. Pueden pasar argumentos a través de sus constructores, extender otras clases, implementar interfaces, y utilizar rasgos al igual que una clase normal:

```
<?php

class Foo {}

$child = new class extends Foo {};

var_dump($child instanceof Foo); // true
```

También los rasgos (`trait`) funcionan de la misma manera que en las definiciones de clase nombradas.

```
trait Foo {
    public function someMethod() {
      return "bar";
    }
}

$anonClass = new class {
    use Foo;
};

var_dump($anonClass->someMethod()); // string(3) "bar"
```

---

### Reflection

El único cambio en la reflexión es agregar `ReflectionClass::isAnonymous()`.

---

### Serialización

La serialización no es compatible y se producirá un error al igual que las funciones anónimas.

---

### Nombre de clase interna

El nombre interno de una clase anónima se genera con una referencia única basada en su dirección.

```
function my_factory_function(){
    return new class{};
}
```

Si ejecutamos:

```
get_class (my_factory_function ())
```

devolverá `"class @ 0x7fa77f271bd0"` incluso si se llama varias veces, ya que es la misma definición. La palabra "`class`" se usa de forma predeterminada, pero si la clase anónima extiende una clase con nombre, se usará esto:

```
class mine {}

new class extends mine {};
```

Este nombre de clase será "`mine@0x7fc4be471000`".

Múltiples clases anónimas creadas en la misma posición (por ejemplo, un bucle) pueden compararse con `==`, pero las creadas en otros lugares no coincidirán ya que tendrán un nombre diferente:

```
$identicalAnonClasses = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
    $identicalAnonClasses[$i] = new class(99) {
        public $i;
        public function __construct($i) {
            $this->i = $i;
        }
    };
}

var_dump($identicalAnonClasses[0] == $identicalAnonClasses[1]); // true

$identicalAnonClasses[2] = new class(99) {
    public $i;
    public function __construct($i) {
        $this->i = $i;
    }
};

var_dump($identicalAnonClasses[0] == $identicalAnonClasses[2]); // false
```

Ambas clases fueron idénticas en todos los sentidos, aparte de su nombre generado.

---

### Casos de uso

Las pruebas de código presentan el número más significativo de casos de uso, sin embargo, donde las clases anónimas son parte de un lenguaje, éstas encuentran su razón de ser en muchos casos de uso, no solo de prueba. Si es técnicamente correcto usar una clase anónima depende casi completamente de una aplicación individual, o incluso de un objeto que depende de la perspectiva.

Algunos puntos rápidos:

- Las pruebas de burla se vuelven fáciles como un pastel. Cree implementaciones sobre la marcha para interfaces, evitando el uso de complejas APIs de burla.
- Mantenga el uso de estas clases fuera del alcance (scope) donde son definidas
- Evita golpear el autocargador (autoloader) para implementaciones triviales.

Ajustar las clases existentes que solo cambian una sola cosa puede hacer esto muy fácil. Tomando un ejemplo de la [biblioteca PHP Pusher](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-php#debugging--logging):

```
// PHP 5.x
class MyLogger {
  public function log($msg) {
    print_r($msg . "\n");
  }
}

$pusher->setLogger( new MyLogger() );

// New Hotness
$pusher->setLogger(new class {
  public function log($msg) {
    print_r($msg . "\n");
  }
});
```

Esto nos permitió crear un nuevo archivo o colocar la definición de clase en la parte superior del archivo o en algún lugar lejos de su uso. Para grandes acciones complejas, o cualquier cosa que necesite ser reutilizada, eso sería mejor como una clase con nombre, pero en este caso es agradable y útil para no molestar.

Si necesita implementar una interfaz muy liviana para crear una dependencia simple:

```
$subject->attach(new class implements SplObserver {
  function update(SplSubject $s) {
    printf("Got update from: %s\n", $subject);
  }
});
```

Aquí hay un ejemplo, que cubre la conversión de middleware PSR-7 a middleware de estilo Laravel 5.

```
<?php
$conduit->pipe(new class implements MiddlewareInterface {
    public function __invoke($request, $response, $next)
    {
        $laravelRequest = mungePsr7ToLaravelRequest($request);
        $laravelNext    = function ($request) use ($next, $response) {
            return $next(mungeLaravelToPsr7Request($request), $response)
        };
        $laravelMiddleware = new SomeLaravelMiddleware();
        $response = $laravelMiddleware->handle($laravelRequest, $laravelNext);
        return mungeLaravelToPsr2Response($response);
    }
});
```

Las clases anónimas presentan la oportunidad de crear el primer tipo de clase anidada en PHP. Puede anidar por razones ligeramente diferentes para crear una clase anónima, por lo que merece un debate:

```
<?php
class Outside {
    protected $data;

    public function __construct($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function getArrayAccess() {
        return new class($this->data) extends Outside implements ArrayAccess {
            public function offsetGet($offset) { return $this->data[$offset]; }
            public function offsetSet($offset, $data) { return ($this->data[$offset] = $data); }
            public function offsetUnset($offset) { unset($this->data[$offset]); }
            public function offsetExists($offset) { return isset($this->data[$offset]); }
        };
    }
}
```

Nota: `Outer` se extiende no para acceder a `$this->data`, que solo se puede pasar a un constructor; extender `Outer` permite que la clase anidada que implementa el permiso `ArrayAccess` ejecute métodos protegidos, declarados en la clase `Outer`, en el mismo `$this->data`, y por referencia, como si fueran la clase `Outer`.

En el ejemplo simple anterior, `Outer::getArrayAccess` aprovecha las clases anónimas para declarar y crear un objeto de interfaz `ArrayAccess` para `Outer`.

Al hacer que `getArrayAccess` sea privado, se puede decir que la clase anónima que crea es una clase privada.

Esto aumenta las posibilidades de agrupar la funcionalidad de sus objetos, puede llevar a una mayor legibilidad, algunos podrían decir más código mantenible.

La alternativa a lo anterior es la siguiente:

```
class Outer implements ArrayAccess {
    public $data;

    public function __construct($data) {
        $this->data;
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset) { return $this->data[$offset]; }
    public function offsetSet($offset, $data) { return ($this->data[$offset] = $data); }
    public function offsetUnset($offset) { unset($this->data[$offset]); }
    public function offsetExists($offset) { return isset($this->data[$offset]); }

}
```

El paso por referencia no se usa en los ejemplos anteriores, por lo que el comportamiento con respecto a `$this->data` debe ser implícito.

La forma en que elija hacerlo para cualquier aplicación específica, ya sea que `getArrayAccess` sea privado o no, ya sea que pase por referencia o no, depende de la aplicación.

Se han sugerido varios casos de uso en [esta lista de correo](http://php.markmail.org/message/sxqeqgc3fvs3nlpa?q=anonymous%20classes%20php), y aquí hay algunos.

El caso de uso es el uso por única vez de una "implementación", donde actualmente es probable que pase devoluciones de llamada a una `Callback*-class` como:

```
$x = new Callback(function() {
    /* do something */
});

/* vs */

$x = new class extends Callback {
    public function doSometing()
    {
        /* do something */
    }
};
```

Imagina que tienes varios métodos abstractos en una interfaz/clase, que necesitarían varias devoluciones de llamada al constructor. También `$this` se asigna a los objetos correctos.

Anular un método específico en una clase es un uso práctico. En lugar de crear una nueva clase que amplíe la clase original, puedes usar una clase anónima y anular los métodos que desees.

Por ejemplo, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

$process = new class extends Process {
    public function start() {
        /* ... */
    }
};
```

En lugar de:

```
namespace My\Namespace\Process;

use Symfony\Component\Process\Process as Base;

class Process extends Base {
    public function start() {
        /* ... */
    }
}

$process = new \My\Namespace\Process\Process;
```

---

### Cambios incompatibles hacia atrás

Nueva sintaxis que no se analizará en versiones anteriores, por lo que no se rompe el BC.

---

### Versión (s) de PHP propuesta (s)

7.0

---

### SAPIs impactados

Todas

---

### Impacto a las extensiones existentes

Sin impacto en las bibliotecas existentes.

---

### Problemas abiertos (bugs)

Ninguna

---

### Alcance futuro

Los cambios realizados por este parche significan que las clases anidadas nombradas son más fáciles de implementar (un poquito).

---

### Referencias

Discusión sobre PHP 7: [ver en este enlace](http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=142478600309800&w=2).

---

Implementación

https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/1118

---

#### Notas:

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Por *parche* quiere decir la introducción de la posibilidad de clases anónimas en el core de PHP 7.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>Se refiere a una `Clase` normal, clásica.</sub>